# Moving code from controller to Model (Thin Controller Fat Model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Hello 
I'm new in RoR. How can I switch my simple controller logic to the model?
My database columns is order_type, quantity, quantity_adjusted

Controller

```
def create

 @product = Product.new(params[:product])

 # This is the control structure I want to move to Model

 if @product.order_type = "Purchase"
  @product.quantity_adjusted = -quantity
 else
  @product.quantity_adjusted = quantity
 end

end
```

Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Thanks
LH

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it. One way, possible the most natural, is to create an instance method like :

```
def adjust_quantity(amount)
  (put logic here)
end
```

in your Product model. Then in your controller, you would do :

```
@product.adjust_quantity(quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback in your model. E.g. `after_create`.

Controller:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])

  if @product.save
    # redirect
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :adjust_quantity

  private

  def adjust_quantity
    if self.order_type == "Purchase"
      self.quantity_adjusted = -quantity
    else
      self.quantity_adjusted = quantity
    end
  end
end
```